# Throw error in YAML file (from python) if environment variable is not set

Tags: yaml, environment-variables

I have a YAML file in which I use environment variables like this

`torch_cache_dir: $TORCH_CACHE_DIR`

I exported `TORCH_CACHE_DIR` variable in the terminal I am working on. Everything is working correctly. The YAML file is being used in a python-centric environment (i.e. the YAML file is used by a python script).

However, if I remove the exported variable by doing

`unset TORCH_CACHE_DIR`

and then run my program, everything still works and I would like instead to get an error thrown since my YAML file cannot find the `TORCH_CACHE_DIR` variable. How can I do it? Is that possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In which context is the YAML file used? YAML by itself is just a data representation format.

Comment: sorry, good point, I forgot to mention that I am in a python environment. So the YAML file is being used/called by a python script. I edited the question.

Comment: This still does not explain how `$TORCH_CACHE_DIR` is replaced by the env variable's value. YAML does not do this. Please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).